# 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

The following assignment statement is in the code for a commandbutton on a form:

```
Range("AvailabilityDataModified").Value = "No"
```

AvailabilityDataModified is a single-celled named range on a sheet called "Controls".  This statement executes properly with no error.

I also have three occurrences of the following statement (virtually identical to the one above) that reside in a sheet's code for multiple event handlers:

```
Range("AvailabilityDataModified").Value = "Yes"
```

My problem is the 3 occurrences of the 2nd instance of code generate the 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed error while the first does not.  This might be a problem with scope; however, I don't believe you need any additional reference info when assigning a value to a named range.  I'm at a loss at this point.

Comment: Are other workbooks activated? Is the scope of the name the workbook or a worksheet?

Comment: According to the Name Manager, the scope of the named range is workbook.  That's what makes this confusing.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no.  The name of the range, "AvailabilityDataModified", together with the cell address, was created with the Name Mangager.

Comment: What happens if you prepend "worksheets("Controls")." before Range?

Comment: You could also try "Thisworkbook.worksheets("Controls").Range("AvailabilityDataModified").Value" or Thisworkbook.worksheets("Controls").[AvailabilityDataModified].Value

Comment: Both @Siphor's suggestions should work (I tested the fist one).`Range` inside a worksheet object refers to `SheetName.Range`, not to the workbook-scoped Range object.

Comment: That worked (and thanks); but, given the sheet name is inherently part of the named range definition, I really don't understand why it is necessary to specify it again.  Explanation?

Comment: Well I mostly guessed(googling for the problem). But Ioannis Comment explains it.

Comment: @BillD, I see what you mean: your comment is true for code modules. In worksheet modules, `Range` means `Sheets("SheetName").Range`, regardless of whether it is named or not. In code modules global named `Ranges` indeed work OK, but in general `Range("A1")` means `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")`. Personally I prepend the [worksheet code name](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm) before the `Range`, to avoid surprises.

Comment: @loannis, that makes sense.  I appreciate the help and advice.

Comment: I finally understand it myself. It is not that it doesnt find the name. the worksheet range just restricts it to cells in the current worksheet and because there are none it returns a error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Worksheets("Controls").Range("AvailabilityDataModified").Value = "Yes"
```

instead.
Inside a worksheet object Range refers to SheetName.Range, not to the workbook-scoped Excel.Application.Range object. This causes the range "AvailabilityDataModified" to be restricted to the sheet of the worksheet object. Because no cells of "AvailabilityDataModified" are in the sheet the Range returns a error.